# PuTTY cannot connect but WinSCP and Git bash can

Tags: ssh, putty

I have a problem: I've been given an account on a testing-box. My public RSA key has been added to my account and I can connect just fine using programs such as WinSCP or Git bash. However, when I try to use PuTTY, like I always do, the server immediately closes the connection, only displaying `Server unexpectedly closed network connection`.

WinSCP also has a feature to open the current connection using PuTTY. Note: I am already successfully connected to the server at this point using my username and public-key. However, this results in the same `Server unexpectedly closed network connection` message immediately.

I have tried to connect to the server with no credentials pre-entered but was unable to do so either (same message).

What reason could this have, and how can this be resolved?

Comment: Have you checked connection with a updated putty version?. I think it could be a protocol version problem.

Comment: @Igor Indeed, this was the only thing I did not try yet. Looks like the latest version of PuTTY does indeed solve the issue. If you make it an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer versions of Putty comes with updated protocols that some ssh servers are using actually. Updating the version to the latest available could solve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try to check the shell configured in /etc/passwd for your user, then check if /etc/ssh/sshd_config allow sftp-only session for your user.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however, a solution to my problem was already found. Furthermore, git bash was able to connect just fine, ruling out SFTP only since it uses regular SSH.